# Extracting element from list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json

I have a list of dictionary objects like this:

```
[{'Id': 46, 'Date': '2016-05-09T00:00:00', 'Type': 1, 'PId': None, 'Ct': None},
{'Id': 108, 'Date': '2017-07-01T00:00:00', 'Type': 10, 'PId': None, 'Ct': None}]
```

I can do this to extract `Date` from the first element of this list:

`list_dict[0].get('Date')`

How can I get the `Date` corresponding to `Type` 10 (without hardcoding that it is the 2nd element in the list)? The solution should return None if `Type` 10 does not exist.

--EDIT:

Previous version of question was assuming that the list was of json objects, they are actually dictionaries

Comment: Are you sure those are json objects and not python dicts? You can just loop over the list, check the type first, and get the date if you found what type you were looking for.

Comment: JSON is a text serialization format. What you have there is some Python object, a list of dicts. Please do not conflate the two.

Comment: thanks @AndrasDeak, I get them as outputs from call to the `requests` python API which returns a json-encoded content of a response.

Comment: @user308827 you probably use the `response.json()` method, which *deserializes the JSON text* into a Python object. Again, please do not conflate the two.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks! wasn't aware of that, will update query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple Loop

You can use a simple loop, getting the first dictionary with `Type` set to `10`.

```
lst = [
    {'Id': 46, 'Date': '2016-05-09T00:00:00', 'Type': 1, 'PId': None, 'Ct': None},
    {'Id': 108, 'Date': '2017-07-01T00:00:00', 'Type': 10, 'PId': None, 'Ct': None},
]
type_10_date = None
for obj in lst:
    if obj.get('Type') == 10:
        type_10_date = obj.get('Date')

print(type_10_date)
# 2017-07-01T00:00:00
```

### Using Filter

You can also use the built-in `filter` function if you choose, which takes a predicate function that determines what values in an iterable (the `list` in this case) should be returned. **Note**: I've included a conversion to a `list` for Python 3 users who get a `filter` object back from the built-in filter function.

```
type_10_objs = list(filter(lambda d: d.get('Type') == 10, lst))
if type_10_objs:  # This could be an empty list!
    print(type_10_objs[0].get('Date'))
# 2017-07-01T00:00:00
```

Comment: thanks @foslock, I get this error `*** AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'get'`. I am using python 3.6

Comment: @user308827 Ah, if you are using Python 3, you will need to turn the `filter` object into a list before you can `[0]` index into it. I will update.

Comment: thanks! also, do you know if your soln will work if lst is empty? i.e. will it return None or will it return error?

Comment: @user308827 If the list is empty, neither will throw an exception, `type_10_date` will be None in the first example, and `type_10_objs` will be an empty list in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the type and return the corresponding date like so:

```
input = [{'Id': 46, 'Date': '2016-05-09T00:00:00', 'Type': 1, 'PId': None, 'Ct': None}, {'Id': 108, 'Date': '2017-07-01T00:00:00', 'Type': 10, 'PId': None, 'Ct': None}]

def example(input):

    for element in input:
        if element['Type'] == 10:
            return element['Date']

    return None
```